# Name resolution for the name 4.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded

Tags: windows-7, networking

In Windows Even Viewer is logged this Warning:

`Name resolution for the name 4.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.`

There is no problem on my ADSL connection and modem. On other windows is no any issue. My system is Win7-64. What is the reason?

Answer (score 3):

Note the address for the host being queried: `4.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa`. That address indicates that you are trying to perform a [reverse lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) for the IP address `192.168.1.4` to retreive its hostname.

192.168.4.x is a private ([RFC1918](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1918.html)) network address, so no Internet DNS server can resolve it. only a DNS server within the 192.168.4. network could respond.

Second, It is not required that a DNS server implement a reverse lookup for every zone it does forward lookups for, so it is entirely natural when performing a reverse lookup for the server to just ignore it, unless it is configured to respond. Combined with the limited scope of servers capable of responding to a private zone request, It is not suprising that you got no response. Furthermore many modern routers provide DNS masquerading and caching, and may not support reverse lookups at all.

So, in sum, the message is not much of a mystery. The Mystery is, what application is trying to perform a reverse lookup on that address, for what purpose, and is that purpose worth the work of resolving the issue, perhaps by installing a local DNS server with the private zone, reconfiguring existing services to provide reverse lookups, etc.

Comment: How can it delete the reverse lookup record?

Comment: I'm afraid your question is not clear. could you please clarify? In particular what is "it" in this context?

Comment: My main problem is, `3 minutes delay` for connecting to internet on `pppoe` connection. in other windows is no any problem and after windows bootup system is connected to internet.

Comment: The error message you posted does not incidate a cause for the delay you indicate. The real issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Other windows error is logged: http://superuser.com/questions/1009189/a-timeout-200000-milliseconds-was-reached-while-waiting-for-a-transaction-resp